# c# sort list through by using int

Tags: c#, list

I'm running a for loop and adding the following properties to a list.

```
public string Url { get; set; }
public string ImageName { get; set; }
public int OrderRank { get; set; }
```

This is my list

```
public List<Image> images { get; set; }
this.images = new List<Image>();
```

My list is populating fine, so i'm getting all the right data in the list. I'm trying to order the list based on the OrderRank which is an int. Any idea on how to go about doing this?

Comment: var list = images.OrderBy(x=>x.OrderRank).ToList();

Comment: Are those properties in a class called Image?